# How to solve PHP array with Json and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Can anybody help me with this problem ? I am trying to display the array that I retrieve from PHP in HTML / Java form.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require('routeros_api.class.php');

$API = new routeros_api();

$API->debug = true;

$API->connect('1.1.1.1', 'admin', '123');
$API->write('/ip/firewall/filter/print');

$READ = $API->read(false);
$ARRAY = $API->parse_response($READ);

echo json_encode ($ARRAY);
$API->disconnect();


?>
```

### output

[{  ".id":"*6", 
    "chain":"unused-hs-chain",
    "action":"passthrough", 
    "log":"false",
    "disabled":"true"},

{  ".id":"*5",
    "chain":"input",
    "action":"accept",
    "log":"false",
    "disabled":"true"},

{  ".id":"*2A",
    "chain":"unused-hs-chain",
    "action":"drop",
    "log":"false",
    "disabled":"true"}]

displayjava.html

```
 <tbody id="myTable">
                    <script>
                        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        var url = "testdata2.php";

                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                                myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                            }
                        }
                        xmlhttp.open("get", url, true);
                        xmlhttp.send();

                        function myFunction(response) {
                            var arr = JSON.parse(response);
                            var i;
                            var outp = "<tbody>";

                            for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                outp += "<tr>" +
                                "<td>" + arr[i].id + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + arr[i].chain + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + arr[i].action + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + arr[i].log + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + arr[i].disabled + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>";
                            }

                            outp += "</tbody>"
                            document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = outp;
                        }
                    </script>


                    </tbody>
```

By the way I am displaying the data in a table form format in html file

Comment: The first thing to do is: Don't generate the JSON manually. Instead, just build up an array of what you want to send back in PHP, then use `json_encode` so it handles the details for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least two problems there:

1. You're outputting invalid JSON:

   ```
   [
       {
           "Name": "*6",
           "City": "unused-hs-chain",
           "City2": "unused-hs-chain",
           "City3": "unused-hs-    chain",
           "Country": "passthrough"
       }{
           "Name": "*5",
           "City": "input",
           "City2": "input",
           "City3": "input",
           "Country": "accept"
       }{
           "Name": "*2A",
           "City": "unused-hs-chain",
           "City2": "unused-hs-ch
   ```

   You need commas between those objects (after each `}` and before the next `{`).

   Don't generate the JSON manually. Instead, just build up an array of what you want to send back in PHP, then use `json_encode` so it handles the details for you.
2. You're using properties on the objects in the array that aren't in the JSON. Your code usese `arr[i].id`, `arr[i].chain`, and `arr[i].action`, but the objects in your JSON don't have `id`, `chain`, or `action` properties, they have `Name`, `City`, `City2`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I using the json_encode to compile into array. Now what should i do so i can display in the html side ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `json_encode()` instead of building it manually.

```
$output = array();
foreach($ARRAY as $rs) {
    $output[] = array(
        'Name' => $rs['id'],
        'City' => $rs['chain'],
        'City2' => $rs['chain'],
        'City3' => $rs['chain'],
        'Country' => $rs['action'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($output);
exit;
```

Your JSON string response right now has missing `{},` commas.

Answer (score 1):

Don't build manually use **json_encode()** function ,

Above code is

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
require('routeros_api.class.php');

$API = new routeros_api();

$API->debug = true;

$API->connect('1.1.1.1', 'admin', '123');
$API->write('/ip/firewall/filter/print');

$READ = $API->read(false);
$ARRAY = $API->parse_response($READ);

$outp = array();
foreach($ARRAY as $rs) {
    $outp[] = array(
        'Name' => $rs['id'],
        'City' => $rs['chain'],
        'City2' => $rs['chain'],
        'City3' => $rs['chain'],
        'Country' => $rs['action'],
    );
}


$API->disconnect();

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

Comment: if your going to copy the foreach part make sure you also change the variable name, it makes it obvious